# Best performance table design for measurments

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-design

I need to create a table which saves measurements consisting of a device id (int), logdate (datetime) and a value (decimal) (SQL Server 2008). The measurements are always on the quarter e.g. 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15... so I was thinking that an int defining the amount of quarters since a certain date would be result in better performance than a datetime.

Retrieving would usually be done using the following:

```
  -where DeviceId = x and QuarterNumber between a and b
  -where DeviceId in (x, y, ...) and QuarterNumber between a and b
  -where DeviceId = x and QuarterNumber = a
```

What would be the best design for this table?

```
PK DeviceId int
PK QuarterNumber int
   Value int
```

or

```
PK MeasurementId int
UQ QuarterNumber int
UQ DeviceId int
   Value int
```

(UQ=unique index)

or something totally different?

Thanks!

Comment: How many quarters are you expecting to record? How many devices are you expecting to be registered?

Comment: about 100.000 devices and I will keep about 96*5 quarters for each device

Comment: I always tend to go for your option 2. In this case I don't know which would be better.  The option 2 would mean that you would mean a bigger table and indexes, but I think inserts would be faster.  I think with option 1 you may have issues because of the clustered index on the PK.

Comment: I found this blog post that resembles my situation. Are his conclusions correct? And is his comment about the fill factor also correct? http://improve.dk/archive/2011/05/24/avoiding-page-splits-byhellip-splitting-pages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might get marginally better SELECT performance by defining the number of quarter hours since a certain date if you have many millions of rows.

Personally, I don't think the marginal performance gain will be worth the reduced readability. I also wouldn't like basing the design on a quarter-hour assumption.  (In my experience, that kind of requirement often changes over time.) You *could* include a quarter-hour CHECK constraint now on a datetime column now, and drop it later if that requirement changes.

But there's no point in relying on opinion when you can test and measure. Build three tables, load several million rows of sample data, and study the query plans. (It's not *completely* impractical to load 50 million rows into each table. I've sometimes loaded 20 million rows into a test table when answering a question on SO.) Don't assume that your first try at indexing will be optimal. Consider multiple indexes, and consider a multi-column index, too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there can be any specific guidelines for your criteria. You might need to create and test(you can insert a demo data in each). Since you want performance improvement I would suggest the use of index in your table.